# Closed form for a look-alike Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

I’m trying to get the closed form for the following sequence:

$x_1=1$, $x_2=x$

\begin{align*}
x_n=x_{n-2}+x^{n-1} \quad\text{if } n\geq3.
\end{align*}

After some calculations the only thing I get is:

\begin{align*}
x_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} x^{2k} \quad\text{if $n$ is odd,}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
x_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} x^{2k+1} \quad\text{if $n$ is even.}
\end{align*}

But I'd like to get a closed form that doesn’t depend on the parity of $n$.

Note that in the summation form, there is a problem when it is the empty sum, since by "convention" it is zero.
Is there a way to get $1$ or $x$ with an empty sum or another way I could fix it?

Comment: I edited my solution with a much more satisfying solution. Check it out and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with [characteristic polynomial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) technique. From:
$$x_n=x_{n-2}+x^{n-1}$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}+x^{n}$$
then
$$x\cdot x_n=x\cdot x_{n-2}+x^{n}$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_{n-1}+x^{n}$$
and
$$x_{n+1}-x\cdot x_n-x_{n-1}+x\cdot x_{n-2}=0$$
with the characteristic polynomial:
$$t^{3}-x\cdot t^{2}-t+x=0 \iff 
(t - 1) (t + 1) (t - x)=0$$
with the roots $-1, 1$ and $x$, leading to the:
$$x_n=A\cdot (-1)^n + B\cdot (1)^n + C\cdot x^n=\\
A\cdot (-1)^n + B + C\cdot x^n$$
What is left is to find $A, B$ and $C$ from:
$$x_1=1=-A + B + C\cdot x$$
$$x_2=x=A + B + C\cdot x^2$$
$$x_3=1+x^2=-A + B + C\cdot x^3$$
a system of linear equations, leading to:
$$C=\frac{x}{x^2-1},
B=-\frac{1}{2\cdot(x-1)},
A=-\frac{1}{2\cdot(x+1)}$$

or
$$x_n=-\frac{(-1)^n}{2\cdot(x+1)} -\frac{1}{2\cdot(x-1)} + \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, both of those finite sums have easily calculable closed formed solutions (they're geometric series). Second, the initial difference equation implies that the two subsequences $(x_1, x_3, x_5,...)$ or $(x_2, x_4, x_6, ...)$ are independent of one another. The presence of the $n-1$ term in the exponent of $x$ may be misleading.

Admittedly, I am not an expert in difference equations, but since the two subsequences are independent, I would not expect a single closed-formed equation to necessarily and "nicely" describe the entire sequence $(x_n)$, unless $x_1$ and $x_2$ are purposely chosen so that this is the case.

There is, however, a way to "cheat" and force a single solution. You can piece together your two solutions (after you've used known formulas for geometric series to simplify them) by using:

$$x_n = \frac{1}{2}[1-(-1)^n]a_n^{(odd)}+\frac{1}{2}[1-(-1)^{n+1}]a_n^{(even)}$$

I personally don't find this particularly more elegant than using a piecewise function that depends on the parity of $n$, but I digress.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the empty sum you mentioned, is the case when $x=0$ because in the summation form, it has a misleading term, $0^0$. Well, the simple way of dealing with this is to express the sum as a single fraction. Here's how I did it, let $G(t)= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n,$ $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} x_nt^n = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} x_{n-2}t^n +\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}x^{n-1}t^n$$ gives $$G(t)-t-xt^2=t^2G(t)+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}x^{n-1}t^n.$$ Solving for $G(t),$ $$\begin{align*} G(t)&= \frac{1}{1-t^2}\left(t+xt^2 + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}x^{n-1}t^n\right) \\ &= \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}t^n\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^{2k}\right).\end{align*}$$ Now, extracting the coefficient of $t^n,$ we get that when $n$ is odd, $$a_n=x^{n-1}+x^{n-3}+\cdots + 1 =\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x^2-1}$$ and when $n$ is even, $$a_n = x^{n-1}+x^{n-3}+\cdots +x = \frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x^2-1}.$$ If you want a single expression for $a_n,$ what I can come up with is $$a_n = \frac{x^{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}((-1)^n-1)-\frac{1}{2}((-1)^n+1)x}{x^2-1}.$$

Comment: I like this solution, it was very helpful, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: In the part when you separate the cases even and odd how did you know how to write down the sums? Is it something like Cauchy product?
I'm triying to do the same with a "harder" sequence and I don't really get it.